# How do I use NavBar for PrimeFaces mobile

Tags: primefaces

I've been trying to understand how to use the NavBar under PrimeFaces mobile and tried to find the answer both here, on the Primefaces forum and using google but haven't found anything helpful yet.

For the showcase I found this part:

```
<pm:view id="navbar">
  <pm:header title="NavBar">
    <f:facet name="left"><p:button value="Back" icon="back" href="#main?reverse=true"/></f:facet>
      <pm:navBar>
        <p:button value="Home" icon="home" href="#main?reverse=true" styleClass="ui-btn-active"/>
        <p:button value="Info" icon="info" href="#main?reverse=true" />
        <p:button value="Search" icon="search" href="#main?reverse=true" />
      </pm:navBar>
    </pm:header>
```

I don't really agree with having the view "outside" of the NavBar, since I want the NavBar to be the same no matter what "tab" I'm on in my app. Am I understanding this wrong or is this the way it is supposed to be?
If that is the way I could accept that, but the next problem I'm facing is that it uses the slide animation. From what I understand the only option I have regarding the animation is to set it to reverse, but I want to turn it off completely in that case.

Have I misunderstood the whole thing? Does any one have some examples using the NavBar that they like to share that would be very appreciated.

// Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I'currently working with PF mobile and for my understanding you're able to insert multiple "tabs" per h:view as described in the manual [here](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_mobile_users_guide_0_9.pdf) (page 9).

Ergo: ONE h:view MANY pm:view, pm:pages (tabs).

If you'd like to show the same NavBar on every tab/page you'll have to make yourself comfortable by adding it in a `pm:view` outside the `pm:page`-tags inside an `pm:header`-tag (for showing it as a fixed NavBar at the top).
It'll be displayed at the top of every page.

Otherwise put it inside the `pm:page`-tag to display a unique NavBar on every tab/page.

The slide animation affects only your created pages not the NavBar.
These animations only show up when you implement more than one page.

Hope this helped, have fun!

### Update:

I couldn't find my snippet and I wasn't able to recode it. So I quickly set up a workaround an hope it'll help you.
I created an `<ui:composition>`-page in my `META-INF`-folder containing the global NavBar.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

<head>
<title>navBar Template</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <pm:navBar>
            <p:button value="Home" icon="home" href="#main?reverse=true" styleClass="ui-btn-active" />
            <p:button value="Info" icon="info" href="#main?reverse=true" />
            <p:button value="Search" icon="search" href="#main?reverse=true" />
        </pm:navBar>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

After that I included my template in every `<pm:view>` by referencing with the `<ui:iclude>`-tag:

```
    <pm:page title="NavBar">
        <pm:view>
            <pm:header title="Welcome" fixed="true" >
                <ui:include src="/META-INF/template/navbar.xhtml" />
            </pm:header>
            <pm:content>
                ...
            </pm:content>
        </pm:view>

        <pm:view id="viewB">
            <pm:header title="B" >
                <ui:include src="/META-INF/template/navbar.xhtml" />
            </pm:header>
            <pm:content>
                B View
            </pm:content>
        </pm:view>
    </pm:page>
```

I'm still on it, but I hope this will help you for now.
As soon as I found some time I'll have a deeper look.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried it, but couldn't get it to work. Have you actually managed to get it to work yourself? If so, do you have some example? I'm currently thinking I might try to create something similar myself, using javascript, just to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I've once tried without any logic lying behind. I'll post it for you if I find it.

Comment: I tried the other suggestion you had as well, but with that I still slides the whole page and not only the component section as I wanted. I will continue to look for a solution, might have to dig a little deeper into how primefaces mobile really works though. Thanks for your help